# Electrical characteristics of the LM358

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, buffer

I am using an LM358 as a voltage follower.

I was reading the electrical characteristics of the IC.  I don't understand why this IC has two electrical characteristics table with different input common mode voltage range and input  and how I should decide like which value I should follow.

[image]

[image]

**DATASHEET**:https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can guarantee the ambient temperature will always be 25°C it would be wise to consider the characteristics over temperature (the worse numbers).

But if your temperature range is very benign maybe you don't need to use the absolute worst case numbers. For the LM358 the limits apply over 0-70°C. If you might want it to work slightly outside that range (eg. outside in winter in Canada) you can either buy the upgraded version (best) or allow even more safety margin than the worse figures.

So, the answer is both and neither. Very zen-like.

Comment: thanks for help@Spehro